# way to loop with register and when terms

Tags: ansible

Thanks to Ansible I need to manage my Website ressources (Logo, Terms...) for my differents customers. I need to list/verify/copy at most 5 files per customers.

To achieve that, I've a specific playbook which today :

- Create shortcut variable for file names (x1)
- Verify that files exist for my customer (x5)
- Copy this file if exist (x5)

My problem : A lot of répetitions in Ansible Syntax to do the same actions..

So, I know this code below doesn't work, but I try to find the best method to have a lighter syntax/répetitions possible.

In the idea, I would to do something like this :

```
  - name: "Creation of shortcut variable for file names"
    set_fact:
      LogoFile:           "{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}/custom/path/of/my/customer/mycustomer_Logo.gif"
      HeadBandLoginFile:  "{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}/custom/path/of/my/customer/mycustomer_HeadBand.png"
      SideBandFile:       "{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}/custom/path/of/my/customer/mycustomer_SideBand.png"
      TermsFile:          "{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}/custom/path/of/my/customer/mycustomer_Terms.pdf"
      LegalNoticeFile:    "{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}/custom/path/of/my/customer/mycustomer_LegalNotice.pdf"

  - name: "Verifying that files exist"
    stat:
      path: "{{ item.file }}"
    register: "{{ item.register }}"
    loop:
    - { file: "{{ LogoFile }}",          register: "Logo"        }
    - { file: "{{ HeadBandLoginFile }}", register: "HeadBand"    }
    - { file: "{{ SideBandFile }}",      register: "SideBand"    }
    - { file: "{{ TermsFile }}",         register: "Terms"       }
    - { file: "{{ LegalNoticeFile }}",   register: "LegalNotice" }
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: "Copy files if exist"
    copy:
      src:  "{{ item.file }}"
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    when: "{{ item.when }}"
    loop:
    - { file: "{{ LogoFile }}",          dest: "/custom/path/to/put/file", when: Logo.stat.exists        }
    - { file: "{{ HeadBandLoginFile }}", dest: "/custom/path/to/put/file", when: HeadBand.stat.exists    }
    - { file: "{{ SideBandFile }}",      dest: "/custom/path/to/put/file", when: SideBand.stat.exists    }
    - { file: "{{ TermsFile }}",         dest: "/custom/path/to/put/file", when: Terms.stat.exists       }
    - { file: "{{ LegalNoticeFile }}",   dest: "/custom/path/to/put/file", when: LegalNotice.stat.exists }
```

Does somebody have an idea to achieve my need doing something like this ? Avoiding 5 repetitions of check files exist and copy file ..

Thanks for all !

EDIT :

The "dest" of files need to be différent for each files. For exemple :

On my Ansible server, files are stored as :

```
/etc/ansible/inventory/deploiements/specific/between/eachclient/personnalisations/specific.between.eachclient_bandeau.png
/etc/ansible/inventory/deploiements/specific/between/eachclient/personnalisations/specific.between.eachclient_bandelaterale.png
/etc/ansible/inventory/deploiements/specific/between/eachclient/personnalisations/specific.between.eachclient_logo.gif
/etc/ansible/inventory/deploiements/specific/between/eachclient/personnalisations/specific.between.eachclient_cgu.pdf
/etc/ansible/inventory/deploiements/specific/between/eachclient/personnalisations/specific.between.eachclient_mentionslegales.pdf
```

And need to be store at destination as :

```
/data/EDT/apache/specific/between/eachclient/htdocs/ressources/ressourcesael/_imgael/_page/_imgael_page_bg_agence_tetiere_default_login.jpg
    /data/EDT/apache/specific/between/eachclient/htdocs/ressources/ressourcesael/_imgael/_page/_imgael_page_bg_page_nav.jpg
    /data/EDT/apache/specific/between/eachclient/htdocs/ressources/ressourcesael/_imgael/_page/_imgael_page_logo.gif
    /data/FLD/apache/specific/between/eachclient/htdocs/ressources/ressourcesael/_txtael/CGUCreationCompte.pdf
    /data/HEB/apache/specific/between/eachclient/htdocs/ressources/ressourcesael/_txtael/MentionsLegales.pdf
```

The path "specific/between/eachclient/" is set thanks to an inventory variable.

So i'm searching for the best way to list if file exist and copy them to the specified dest if applicable.

Dyl'

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Copy file if it exists.**"*

A: For example, given the files

```sh
shell> tree c1
c1
├── f1
├── f2
└── f3
```

and the variables

```yaml
    flist: [f1, f2, f3, f4]
    my_customer: c1
    path_to_put_files: dest
```

the tasks below

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: "{{ my_customer }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ flist }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ item.stat.path }} to {{ path_to_put_files }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results|selectattr('stat.exists')|list }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg: Copy c1/f1 to dest
  msg: Copy c1/f2 to dest
  msg: Copy c1/f3 to dest
```

Comment: Done sorry, you can delete your comment too

Comment: Take a look at my answer as a hint of what `minimal` in [mre] means.